# Margin top negatif issue

Tags: html, css, margin

I have an issue when i would like to scroll my block horizontal, there is a movement that I would like to delete when I scroll with a pad or on screen, it's a vertical movement on the block container-mobile, this movement is due to the margin top negatif on the block slide
You can see that on this example and on the mode IPHONE X/XS/11 PRO
[enter link description here](https://jsitor.com/yPRhVIn9s)

How can i delete it ?

Comment: Please post your code here and expand on what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change overflow-x: scroll to overflow-x: hidden;

```
#container-mobile {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top: 100px !important;
    /* pour ie et mozilla */
    -ms-overlow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Note that the scroll behavior is rotated because you probably rotate the element.

**Update**

To fix the problem about the inversion of scroll you should replace this CSS classes in this way:

```
.slide {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: -250px !important;
}

.blocHorizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 400vw;    
}

#container-mobile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-top: 100px !important;
    /* pour ie et mozilla */
    -ms-overlow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your return, your comment resolved my issue, nevertheless that prodcuces an other, now the scroll is not work because of this overflow, how can i resolve that ?

Comment: Scroll work, just in the wrong direction. If you try to scroll it vertically it scroll horizontally. You should avoid to rotate the element you scroll, Instead rotate the image and insert it in the element to scroll

Comment: @KévinWernet Check the update in my answer to fix it. And please post your code also in your question so the answer could be useful also for others users looking for a similar problem.